# How to set CLion custom CMake executable to a version installed with Homebrew?

Tags: cmake, homebrew, clion

I'm trying to make CLion use the same version of CMake that I'm using from the command line. In Preferences > Build, Execution, Deployment > Toolchains, I tried setting a custom CMake executable path to /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.7.0/bin, but CMake displays a "not found" error on the same page.

For now, I had brew install the same version of CMake that CLion is using: `brew switch cmake 3.6.2`

But is there a way to make CLion use the version of cmake installed with brew?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, you can set your own `cmake` binary for use in Clion.

You're on the right track, go to `Preferences > Build, Execution, Deployment > Toolchains` just as you did, and set `CMake executable -> Custom` to

```
 /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.7.0/bin/cmake
```

Note, your're supposed to put the absolute name of your own cmake here, not only the path to the directory containing `cmake`.

Comment: Oh duh, I tried all the directory paths but not the cmake executable path